# How is it possible that the operating system is still running during VeraCrypt wipe

Tags: delete

VeraCrypt is a software to encrypt disk. During the installation, you can choose to wipe the disk in order to prevent overwriting data and be able to recover it.

During the wipe operation, the operating system is still running...

Do you know how VeraCrypt proceed to avoid the operating system from crashing?

Thanks

Comment: The operating systems is in memory once it's booted -- it doesn't need the disk.

Comment: I'm agree with you, however he still need some critical files on the disk. If an I/O operation occurs on these critical files during the wipe, there is a lot of chance that the operating system crash right?

Comment: What critical files?  The OS doesn't depend on any files once it's up and running.

Comment: Maybe it's a lack of knowledge, but what about some sensitive process like explorer.exe that may crash if you delete some files from the hard drive? Well, there are sensitive process that may use files directly from the hard drive and crash if the disk is being wiped...  For example, you can see : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/931702/windows-explorer-crashes-when-you-try-to-remove-the-windows.old-folder-from-a-computer-that-has-been-upgraded-to-windows-vista

Comment: This being _unix_ stackexchange, I assumed we were talking about a Unix-like OS.  I'm not sure about Windows.  And to be clear, a process crashing isn't the OS crashing.  In a Unix-like OS, some system process can depend on files.  For an application that wipes a hard drive, my bet is that there are very few applications, other than the wipe itself, running when the wipe is performed.